# How to use !Sub or !Join in "AWS::CloudFormation::Init", file key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm currently creating a yaml template and I'm trying to modularize templates so that they can be re-used across different projects. The issue I'm having is that I keep getting syntax errors if I try to use !Join or !Sub in file name.

```
files: 
 /tmp/myfile2.txt: 
   content: "/tmp/myfile1.txt"
   mode: "120644"
```

I want to create a project specific directory instead of /tmp/, for example:

```
files: 
  /PROJECT_NAME/myfile2.txt: 
    content: "/tmp/myfile1.txt"
    mode: "120644"
```

PROJECT_NAME being a CloudFormation parameter.

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
files: 
  !Sub "/${PROJECT_NAME }/myfile2.txt": 
    content: |
      some shell commands
      some shell commands
      some shell commands
    mode: "120644"
```

I tried multiple ways of achieveing this, using !Join,  Fn::Sub, !Sub.

Just wondering if anyone had done anything like this before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just wondering if anyone had done anything like this before?

Many people tried and filed. The reason is that you can't use non-strings as maps in CloudFormation. From [CFN format specification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-resource-specification-format.html):

> A **map** is a collection of key-value pairs, where the **keys are always strings**.

Therefore, a proposed solution is to use `UserData` to define the dynamically generate file, instead of using CFN metadata.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.

Comment: @Lukas No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a fixed file name (the "key" in your key/value pair), and have an immediate command to rename it, since you are allowed to use variables in commands. Something like:

```
  LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          default:
            - my-config
        my-config:
          files:
            /tmp/myfile2.txt:
              content: !Sub |
                My account is ${AWS::AccountId}.
              mode: "000644"
          commands:
            01-rename-file:
              command: !Sub "mkdir -p /tmp/${AWS::AccountId} && mv /tmp/myfile2.txt /tmp/${AWS::AccountId}/myfile2.txt"
```

I'm using the default AWS account id, but you can just replace with `${PROJECT_NAME}` if you have it defined.